# Why It Isn't Displaying (React Small App)

Tags: reactjs

I cannot figure out why the text isn't displaying? The header class should be exporting the render function which should have the header in it.

App.js:

```
    import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import header from './Components/header';


function App() {
  return (
    <header />
  );
}

export default App;
```

header.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class header extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div> <h1> dfdfd </h1></div>
        );
  }
}

export default header;
```

Comment: make the class name `Header` and use `export default Header`

Comment: That is it thank you!

Comment: please , upote and accept the answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use Uppercase for the function 'header'

```
import Header from "./Components/header";

function App() {
  return <Header />;
}

export default App;
```

note: filename lowercase is okay.

EDIT:

More details example:

`App.js`

```
import { header as Header } from "./Components/header";

function App() {
  return <Header />;
}

export default App;
```

`header.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {" "}
        <h1> dfdfd </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// export default header; // No Problem if you 'import Header from "/path/to/file"'
export { header }; // Must be 'import {header: Header} from "/path/to/file"'
```

but I suggest to always write your component class / function name start with uppercase.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! can I ask what is the relationship between the file name and the class name or function names? Or are they not really related other than the import statement.

Comment: filename only affects the importing path, className is okay if you write it in lowercase, but there is an exception, when you are importing a class to use it as a component, it MUST start with uppercase. I will add a little edit to my post.

Comment: Excellent, thank you sir. Weird rule they made with uppercases. I'd like to know the story behind that. In any case many thanks!

Comment: Well, i don't know what is the reason they created it like that. But I think it is for readability. With writing uppercase tag, you can tell the difference between HTML built-in tag, and your own/library Component tag easily.

Answer (score 0):

Header component should start its name with capital case

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div> <h1> dfdfd </h1></div>
        );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the Class name capital `Header` and export it using `export default Header`

**App.js**

```
 import logo from './logo.svg';
 import './App.css';
 import Header from './Components/header';


 function App() {
   return (
     <Header />
   );
 }

export default App;
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Header extends Component {
   render() {
   return ( 
     <div> <h1> dfdfd </h1></div>
     );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to be something like this:

#### Modified App.js

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header';


function App() {
  return (
    <Header />
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Modified Header.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div>
      <h1>
        dfdfd
      </h1>
    </div>
   );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Notice how I changed your `header.js` to `Header.js` with an uppercase `H`. React does not like it when you name your components starting with a lower case alphabet. Just rename your `header.js` to `Header.js` and it should start to work.

Cheers,

Arjis Chakraborty.